# New a better way of initializing classes and objects

Tags: iphone

Here is a code that I thought of to initialize my picker with. Is there a better way to write this?

### The interface

```
@interface roomsClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger roomID;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *desc;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger roomID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *desc;

@end

@interface typesClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger typeID;
    NSString *name;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger typeID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;

@end
```

### The implementation

```
NSMutableArray *tempArrayA = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.roomsArray = tempArrayA;
[tempArrayA release];

roomsClass *tempObjA1 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA1.roomID = 202; 
tempObjA1.name = @"MH202";
tempObjA1.desc = @"Lab";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA1];
[tempObjA1 release];

roomsClass *tempObjA2 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA2.roomID = 207; 
tempObjA2.name = @"MH207";
tempObjA2.desc = @"Office";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA2];
[tempObjA2 release];

roomsClass *tempObjA3 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA3.roomID = 208; 
tempObjA3.name = @"MH208";
tempObjA3.desc = @"Office";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA3];
[tempObjA3 release];

roomsClass *tempObjA4 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA4.roomID = 209; 
tempObjA4.name = @"MH209";
tempObjA4.desc = @"Lab";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA4];
[tempObjA4 release];

roomsClass *tempObjA5 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA5.roomID = 210; 
tempObjA5.name = @"MH210";
tempObjA5.desc = @"Lab";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA5];
[tempObjA5 release];

roomsClass *tempObjA6 = [[roomsClass alloc] init];
tempObjA6.roomID = 211; 
tempObjA6.name = @"MH211";
tempObjA6.desc = @"Office";
[roomsArray addObject:tempObjA6];
[tempObjA6 release];

NSMutableArray *tempArrayB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.typesArray = tempArrayB;
[tempArrayB release];

typesClass *tempObjB1 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB1.typeID = 1; 
tempObjB1.name = @"Desktop";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB1];
[tempObjB1 release];

typesClass *tempObjB2 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB2.typeID = 2; 
tempObjB2.name = @"Laptop";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB2];
[tempObjB2 release];

typesClass *tempObjB3 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB3.typeID = 3; 
tempObjB3.name = @"Monitor";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB3];
[tempObjB3 release];

typesClass *tempObjB4 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB4.typeID = 4; 
tempObjB4.name = @"Server";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB4];
[tempObjB4 release];

typesClass *tempObjB5 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB5.typeID = 5; 
tempObjB5.name = @"Printer";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB5];
[tempObjB5 release];

typesClass *tempObjB6 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB6.typeID = 6; 
tempObjB6.name = @"Projector";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB6];
[tempObjB6 release];

typesClass *tempObjB7 = [[typesClass alloc] init];
tempObjB7.typeID = 7; 
tempObjB7.name = @"Other";
[typesArray addObject:tempObjB7];
[tempObjB7 release];


if (roomPicker == nil) {
    roomPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    roomPicker.delegate = self;
    roomPicker.dataSource = self;
    roomPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    roomPicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    roomPicker.tag = kRoomPicker;
}

txtRoomID.inputView = roomPicker;


if (typePicker == nil) {
    typePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    typePicker.delegate = self;
    typePicker.dataSource = self;
    typePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    typePicker.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0);
    typePicker.tag = kTypePicker;
}

txtTypeID.inputView = typePicker;
```

The idea is to have the picker show some text, but when the user selects the text on the UIPickerView, the integer value/id of the selection be placed in the UITextField, rather than the text the user sees.

I am using iOS 4.3.1 on the device, with 4.3 SDK, and Xcode 3.2.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one way to reduce the redundancy is called a convenience constructor. a partial implementation is illustrated below:

```
@interface MONRoomsClass : NSObject {
    NSInteger roomID;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *desc;
}

@property (nonatomic, readwrite) NSInteger roomID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
/* note: ivar would normally be named 'description' */
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *desc;

/* designated initializer */
- (id)initWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                name:(NSString *)inName 
                desc:(NSString *)inDesc;

/* convenience constructor */
+ (MONRoomsClass *)newRoomsClassWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                                      name:(NSString *)inName
                                      desc:(NSString *)inDesc;

/* convenience constructor */
+ (MONRoomsClass *)roomsClassWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                                   name:(NSString *)inName
                                   desc:(NSString *)inDesc;

@end

@implementation MONRoomsClass

- (id)initWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                name:(NSString *)inName
                desc:(NSString *)inDesc
{
/* error checking omitted */
    self = [super init];
    if (0 != self) {
        roomID = inRoomID;
        name = [inName copy];
        desc = [inDesc copy];

    }
    return self;
}

+ (MONRoomsClass *)newRoomsClassWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                                      name:(NSString *)inName
                                      desc:(NSString *)inDesc
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithRoomID:inRoomID name:[inName desc:inDesc];
}

+ (MONRoomsClass *)roomsClassWithRoomID:(NSInteger)inRoomID
                                   name:(NSString *)inName
                                   desc:(NSString *)inDesc
{
    return [[[self alloc] initWithRoomID:inRoomID
                                    name:inName
                                    desc:inDesc] autorelease];
}

@end

void in_use() {

/* ... */

    MONRoomsClass * roomsClass =
                      [MONRoomsClass newRoomsClassWithRoomID:210
                                                        name:@"MH210"
                                                        desc:@"Lab"];
    [roomsArray addObject:roomsClass];

/* or */
    [roomsArray addObject:
       [[MONRoomsClass newRoomsClassWithRoomID:210
                                          name:@"MH210"
                                          desc:@"Lab"]
                                          autorelease]];
/* or */
    [roomsArray addObject:
         [MONRoomsClass roomsClassWithRoomID:210
                                        name:@"MH210"
                                        desc:@"Lab"]];

/* ... */

}
```

Comment: I ended up using this solution. After reviewing my implementation, I've found this to be a better solution. Thanks again.

Comment: The more I look at this solution, the more I like it. The main reason are, this is object-oriented and its all Objective-C.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities for rewriting your array initialisation code. One that comes to mind is:

```
NSInteger roomIDs[]   = {      202,       207,      208,      209,       210,       211 };
NSString *roomNames[] = {  @"MH202", @"MH207",  @"MH208", @"MH209", @"MH210",  @"MH211" };
NSString *roomDescs[] = { @"Office",   @"Lab", @"Office",   @"Lab",   @"Lab", @"Office" };

NSUInteger numberOfRooms = sizeof(roomIDs) / sizeof(NSInteger);
self.roomsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfRooms];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++) {
    roomsClass *room = [[[roomsClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    room.roomID = roomIDs[i];
    room.name = roomNames[i];
    room.desc = roomDescs[i];
    [self.roomsArray addObject:room];
}
```

or

```
typedef struct {
    NSInteger roomId;
    NSString *name;
    NSString *desc;
} RoomData;

RoomData rooms[] = {
    { 202, @"MH202", @"Office" },
    { 207, @"MH207", @"Lab"    },
    { 208, @"MH208", @"Office" },
    { 209, @"MH209", @"Lab"    },
    { 210, @"MH210", @"Lab"    },
    { 211, @"MH211", @"Office" }
};

NSUInteger numberOfRooms = sizeof(rooms) / sizeof(RoomData);
self.roomsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:numberOfRooms];

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++) {
    roomsClass *room = [[[roomsClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    room.roomID = rooms[i].roomId;
    room.name = rooms[i].name;
    room.desc = rooms[i].desc;
    [self.roomsArray addObject:room];
}
```

If you couple those with @Justin’s convenience constructor, the `for` loop can be simplified to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++) {
    [self.roomsArray addObject:[roomsClassWithRoomID:roomIDS[i]
                                                name:roomNames[i]
                                                desc:roomDescs[i]]];
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRooms; i++) {
    [self.roomsArray addObject:[roomsClassWithRoomID:rooms[i].roomId
                                                name:rooms[i].name
                                                desc:rooms[i].desc]];
}
```

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thank you for taking the time to write the whole code. This technique goes very well with my future enhancement of the code to fill the roomIDs[], roomNames[], and roomDescs[] array with data coming from sqlite3 database.

Comment: Question: I noticed that in your second answer, you changed the NSObject to a C struct. Was there a disadvantage to use NSObject? I was trying to keep the code as object-oriented as possible.

Comment: @FoRum I’ve only used C structs because of syntax convenience. It’s easy to initialise an array of structures like `{{…}, {…}, …}`. The code is more compact and easier to read.